# Cambiar tamaño de los divautomáticamente

Tags: javascript, html, css

me encantaría evitar este error de Auto escalamiento con CSS que deja unos enormes espacios en blanco por los nombres largos de las películas. Alguien me ayudaría a como resolverlo? Aquí les dejo mi código del DIV y el CSS

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

HTML

```
<div class="col-md-2 w3l-movie-gride-agile">
                                <a href="single.html" class="hvr-shutter-out-horizontal"><img src="imagen/malefica.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
                                    <div class="w3l-action-icon"><i class="fa fa-play-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
                                </a>
                                <div class="mid-1 agileits_w3layouts_mid_1_home">
                                    <div class="w3l-movie-text">
                                        <h6><a href="single.html">Maléfica: La dueña de Mal</a></h6>                            
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="mid-2 agile_mid_2_home">
                                        <p>2019</p>
                                        <div class="block-stars">
                                            <ul class="w3l-ratings">
                                                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>7.4</a></li>
                                                
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="ribben">
                                    <p>NEW</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

CSS

```
.w3l-movie-gride-agile {
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgb(255 255 255 / 35%);
    margin-right: 0%;
    margin-bottom: 3%;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 0;
}
.col-md-2 {
    width: 16.66666667%;
}
```

Comment: todos los div "col-md-2 w3l-movie-gride-agile" deben tener height: 100%.

Comment: Te refieres que debo cambiar todos los div a height: 100% ?

Comment: Me parece que estás usando `float` para posicionar los elementos; te sugiero cambiar a [flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mmmm no esta claro tu pregunta, pero creo que podrias solucionarlo con

`overflow: hidden` o final de cuentas dandole un `max-height: 200px` por poner un ejemplo

Comment: No, no me funciona. pero gracias por ayudar. Te daré la palomita

Comment: Envia el codigo completo y te lo solicionare, es que no esta claro el codigo actual para replicar el problema, podrias usar CodePen

Comment: Ya lo pude resolver, muchas gracias :)